# Why does the output of “last” in macOS 10.12 (Sierra) show seemingly nothing but “crash” entries?

Tags: macos, terminal

I just upgraded my Mac mini (Late 2012) to macOS 10.12 (Sierra) and noticed something strange: When running the [`last`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/last.1.html) command in the Terminal—which shows you a history of user logins, reboots and shutdowns—seemingly all of the entries are now indicating “crash” when I can assure you this system has never crashed since the upgrade.

Here is the output of `last` on my system:

```
my_mac:~ jake$ last 
jake      ttys001                   Sat Sep 24 09:05   still logged in
jake      ttys000                   Sat Sep 24 09:05   still logged in
jake      console                   Sat Sep 24 09:01   still logged in
reboot    ~                         Sat Sep 24 09:00 
jake      ttys000                   Sat Sep 24 09:00 - crash  (00:00)
jake      ttys000                   Sat Sep 24 01:19 - crash  (07:41)
jake      ttys000                   Sat Sep 24 00:13 - crash  (08:47)
jake      ttys000                   Fri Sep 23 23:45 - crash  (09:15)
jake      console                   Fri Sep 23 22:45 - crash  (10:15)
reboot    ~                         Fri Sep 23 22:44 
jake      ttys000                   Fri Sep 23 07:35 - crash  (15:08)
jake      ttys000                   Fri Sep 23 07:31 - crash  (15:12)
jake      console                   Fri Sep 23 07:00 - crash  (15:43)
reboot    ~                         Fri Sep 23 06:59 
jake      ttys000                   Thu Sep 22 22:56 - crash  (08:03)
jake      ttys000                   Thu Sep 22 22:03 - crash  (08:56)
jake      ttys000                   Thu Sep 22 21:21 - crash  (09:38)
jake      ttys001                   Thu Sep 22 21:18 - crash  (09:41)
jake      ttys000                   Thu Sep 22 21:16 - crash  (09:42)
jake      ttys000                   Thu Sep 22 19:59 - crash  (10:59)
jake      ttys000                   Thu Sep 22 19:23 - crash  (11:36)
_mbsetupuser  console                   Thu Sep 22 08:35 - crash  (22:24)
jake      console                   Thu Sep 22 08:26 - crash  (22:33)
reboot    ~                         Thu Sep 22 08:21
```

Typically that output should reflect `reboot` for a cold boot or even a warm reboot. That data can be gleaned now by running `last reboot` as shown here:

```
my_mac:~ jack$ last reboot
reboot    ~                         Sat Sep 24 09:00 
reboot    ~                         Fri Sep 23 22:44 
reboot    ~                         Fri Sep 23 06:59 
reboot    ~                         Thu Sep 22 08:21
```

But it still seems odd/broken to me since I’m quote confident this behavior was not the case in Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) or previous versions of Mac OS X since the main reason I use `last` like this is to casually keep track of the last times I shut down or restarted the system.

***NOTE:*** Yes, that [`last` man page I link to on the Apple website](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/last.1.html) states that the entry is for Mac OS X 10.9 and is a “retired” document, the output of `man last` on my macOS 10.12 system is 100% the same.

Comment: Having the user session terminated by `crash` might just be a bug

Comment: The reboots show up, even in your `last` output above. It's "just" that the user sessions are terminated by "crash" instead of "shutdown" (or whatever was the reason before). If `last` hasn't changed it's probably macOS which writes the utmp records differently.